# UPDATE Syntax Error in Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, triggers

I need to update my column with trigger automaticly.

Here is code:

```
create trigger sum update on `cash`
for each row
begin
UPDATE `cash`
SET `sum_cash` = `cash` + `sum_cash`;
end;
$$
```

And I got following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update on `cash` for each row begin UPDATE cash` SE' at line 1
```

I work on MySQL.

Comment: Is `cash` both a table, and a field on that table, e.g. `cash.cash` ? You are using it as both table / field, and its not clear if thats by design.

Comment: yes, it's both field and name

Comment: Do you really want to update ***all*** rows of your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger my_sum after update on `cash`
for each row
begin
UPDATE `cash`
SET `sum_cash` = `cash` + `sum_cash`;
end;
$$
```

You missed the `after` or `before` keyword. Also I changed trigger name since `sum` is a keyword.